# How do I enable psuedo locales in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, localization, right-to-left

**The problems**

1. I am trying to ensure I have right-to-left localization done correctly in my Xamarin Forms app.
2. If and when I do actually get this pseudo-locale enabled, do I need to have my localization file for it with all the strings typed backward, or do I have it normal left-to-right English? (makes more sense after reading the rest)

**The research**

I saw that Android [has a pseudo-locale](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/pseudolocales) specifically for checking bidirectional text, while using English characters so I can read it and verify that it's doing what I think it should. (I don't read/speak/understand any of the languages that are actually right-to-left) The only problem, however, is that I don't know how to use that language in my app.

It looks to me from these docs like the language should be en-XB, but the Android emulator I'm running has the language choice named Arabic (Psuedo-BiDi), so it might be ar-XB, but I can't find anywhere what the language-region code actually is.

I have seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left#android) that I need to enable RtL and target a minSDK of Android 17+ in the AndroidManifest, which I do.

[The Android doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/pseudolocales#enable_pseudolocales) says you need to enable pseudo-locales in the build.gradle, but Xamarin does not have that, so I don't know if I either need to do something similar in a different location like the project file, or just don't need to do anything to have it enabled.

**The attempts**

For all of this, I [ensured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjKob.png) I had the BiDi pseudo-locale selected on the emulator.

I tried adding en-XA, en-XB, ar-XA, and ar-XB files to my project, with identifiers at the start of each string in those files to know if it was using the file and just not going RtL, but those files were ignored.

When I Run the app and check
`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`
or
`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`
or
`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture`
they all said it was en-US, and in the TextInfo, it said `IsRightToLeft = false`.

If I do
`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures)`
that returns the full list of 342 cultures. I didn't look through all of them, but if I try to get the ones that are RtL, and group them by the `TwoLetterISOLanguageName`, I see 7, most of which are not relevant. Looking through the Arabic ones (since on the emulator it calls it Arabic Psuedo-BiDi) I don't see any that looks like the one I have selected, or like the Android doc.

I tried adding a line to the Debug profile in the project file like it seems to do in the Android docs
`<AndroidPsuedoLocalesEnabled>true</AndroidPseudoLocalesEnabled`
but that didn't do anything.

Is this just something that's not enabled/supported in Xamarin yet?

Comment: Have you set the `FlowDirection` property on the pages or root layout of your app?

Comment: Not as of yet, I wanted to see first if this language on its own would show up correctly Right to Left.Actually doing the `FlowDirection` changes throughout the app will take quite a while, so I have been trying to figure out if we can separate out doing the translation from fully changing the whole UI, or if it needs to be done all at once.

Comment: I have now done a few pages with the `FlowDirection` changes, and while it does flip the direction for layouts, it doesn't change the direction of the text within. I also wanted to ensure that the strings themselves are displayed right-to-left as they're supposed to be. `FlowDirection` on a Label specifically doesn't change it either.

Comment: Do you want the strings are displayed right-to-left? Is this true for every character? This may not seem so user-friendly.

Comment: Isn't that how right-to-left languages work? The first character is displayed on the right, the second to its left, etc. ? So if I were to have the string "Test!" in my Locale file, it should show in the Label as "!tseT", right? And that would be determined by the specific Language itself, so in English since the FlowDirection would be left-to-right, it would show as "Test!" still. That's my understanding. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can try running the official sample. When we add `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"` to the pages of the app, the text of the page is displayed on the right side of the screen, rather than every character is displayed in reverse from right to left. The sample is  [Xamarin.Forms TodoLocalized RTL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/todolocalizedrtl).